# how to protect outdoor cables

Tags: security, cable-management

I've installed some outdoor security cameras and ran the Cat5e cables along the outside of the walls. Now I want to protect the parts where the cables are exposed to the sun. What are my options? I was thinking to use some kind of spiral wrap.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

### Paint

All the answers posted so far entail shielding devices *which themselves will require paint* to last very long under UV light bombardment.  So with or without them, you will need a suitable primer and paint.

I recommend running a Scotchbrite pad down the wire or shield before priming, to give the material some microscopic "tooth" for the primer to lock into.  Then a solvent based primer.   Then an exterior rated paint of your choice.

If you want to match what you have on the house, find a way to remove something that is painted in that color, and the hardware store can match it with their scanner.

Comment: Paint would be very easy and effectively block the UV. +

Answer (score 1):

The Cat5e cable is somewhat fragile and the insulation will degrade left exposed the UV light and elements. I suggest using a flexible conduit. You will be protecting the cable from the elements and signal degradation.

Comment: Hmm looked at Home Depot and there's so many options

http://www.homedepot.com/c/best_conduit_choices_from_plastic_pvc_to_metallic_HT_BG_EL

Answer (score 1):

When installing security camera outsides, make sure the connection between the camera and the cable is well protected. To do that, you need to use waterproof cable cap to make sure you cover the jack and the port with protective cover. As for the cable exposing outside, use protective tape to make sure the cable is not easily exposed to the element but not too much to cause heat. For better understanding, you can use plastic conduit to provide extra layer of protection and you can refer to these two articles https://reolink.com/how-to-run-security-camera-wires/ and https://www.securitycameraking.com/securityinfo/cctv-installation-and-wiring-options/.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase and install cable race ways that are typically made out of plastic.

An alternative to consider is to split PVC pipe down the middle of its length to create a cross section that looks like below. Then install this with fasteners or clamp devices over the wiring.

[image]